# Ltablex customize caption

Tags: tables, captions, longtable

I use `ltablex` package for creating tables. 
How can i change the caption name for the continuation of the table, as in the picture?

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`ltablex` combines `longtable` and `tabularx`. `longtable` provides commands to define a first and a general header as well as a general and a last footer. These commands are actually used in the (admittedly brief) [`ltablex` documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/ltablex/ltablex.pdf), but a continued caption, which would be used in the general header (or footer), is not part of the example. The header/footer commands are described in the [`longtable` documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/tools/longtable.pdf).

The code given below shows their use with `ltablex`. The continued caption is defined in the general header. I've also added an example using `longtabu` from the more recent `tabu` package, which offers a convenient way to define flexible `X` columns.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{ltablex}
%if longtabu is used, longtable needs to be loaded (which ltablex already does in this document)
%\usepackage{longtable} 
\usepackage{tabu}

\textheight4in                      %to force a page break after a few rows
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}   %improve spacing

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{XX}     
        \caption{A Table}\\
        \toprule
        First Header &  \\
        \toprule
    \endfirsthead
        \caption{A Table (continued)}\\
        \toprule        
        Header & \\
        \toprule
    \endhead
        \bottomrule
        Footer &  \\
        \bottomrule
    \endfoot
        \bottomrule
        Last Footer &  \\
        \bottomrule    
    \endlastfoot     

    Text & \lipsum[75]\\
    Text & \lipsum[75]\\
    Text & \lipsum[75]\\
\end{tabularx}

\begin{longtabu} to \textwidth {X[1,l]      %aligned left
                                X[2,l]}     %twice as wide as first column
        \caption{A Table}\\
        \toprule
        First Header &  \\
        \toprule
    \endfirsthead
        \caption{A Table (continued)}\\
        \toprule        
        Header & \\
        \toprule
    \endhead
        \bottomrule
        Footer &  \\
        \bottomrule
    \endfoot
        \bottomrule
        Last Footer &  \\
        \bottomrule    
    \endlastfoot
    Text & \lipsum[75]\\
    Text & \lipsum[75]\\
    Text & \lipsum[75]\\
\end{longtabu}

\end{document}
```