# Align table caption with left border of longtable

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, captions, longtable

Subj.

I cannot use `singlelinecheck=off` because it aligns it to the left border of the page.
And why table is too narrow?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{article}
\usepackage[left=35mm,right=15mm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm,bindingoffset=0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc} % указать кодировку русского текста
\usepackage[russian]{babel} % указать, что язык текста - русский

\usepackage{cmap}

\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\usepackage{indentfirst} 
\setlength{\parindent}{1.25cm}

\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{labelsep=endash}

\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
    \keepXColumns
        \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{| l | X |} 

        \caption{A long description of this awesomest table ever. No, seriously.}\\
        \hline 
        First & Second\\ \hline \hline
        \endfirsthead
        \captionsetup{singlelinecheck=off}
        \caption{A short one}\\
        \hline 
        First & Second\\ \hline
        \endhead
        Lols & \lipsum[150] \\ \hline
        Lols & \lipsum[150] \\ \hline
        Lols & \lipsum[150] \\ \hline
        Lols & \lipsum[150] \\ \hline
        Lols & \lipsum[150] \\ \hline
        Lols & \lipsum[150] \\ \hline
        Lols & \lipsum[150] \\ \hline
        Lols & \lipsum[150] \\ \hline
        Lols & \lipsum[150] \\ \hline
        Lols & \lipsum[150] \\ \hline
        Lols & \lipsum[150] \\ \hline
        \end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using `{|l|X|}`. Instead if you use `{|X|X|}`, you will get two columns of equal width and table spans the text width. But the table will look ugly in that case. Hence you may try something like `\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|l|p{.89\textwidth}|}`.

Your first point is not so clear. You don't want to have the cption to be aligned at left margin? In such case you can put `\captionsetup{singlelinecheck=off,margin=0cm}`. You can play with the margin value as your wish.

The MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{article}
\usepackage[left=25mm,right=15mm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm,bindingoffset=0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc} % указать кодировку русского текста
\usepackage[russian]{babel} % указать, что язык текста - русский

\usepackage{cmap}

\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\usepackage{indentfirst}
\setlength{\parindent}{1.25cm}

\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{labelsep=endash}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
%     \keepXColumns
        \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|l|p{.89\textwidth}|}
                \captionsetup{singlelinecheck=off,margin=0cm,format=hang} %% Try format=hang for a change
        \caption{A long description of this awesomest table ever. No, seriously.}\\
        \hline
        First & Second\\ \hline \hline
        \endfirsthead

        \caption{A short one}\\
        \hline
        First & Second column of the table\\ \hline
        \endhead
        Lols & \lipsum[150] \\ \hline
        Lols & \lipsum[150] \\ \hline
        Lols & \lipsum[150] \\ \hline
        Lols & \lipsum[150] \\ \hline
        Lols & \lipsum[150] \\ \hline
        Lols & \lipsum[150] \\ \hline
        Lols & \lipsum[150] \\ \hline
        Lols & \lipsum[150] \\ \hline
        Lols & \lipsum[150] \\ \hline
        Lols & \lipsum[150] \\ \hline
        Lols & \lipsum[150] \\ \hline
        \end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why the table doesn't stretch. But here's an alternative, replacing `ltablex` with the more recent `longtabu` environment. Another `longtabu` example directly compared to an `ltablex` one can be found in the answer to [Ltablex customize caption](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59309/ltablex-customize-caption).

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{article}
\usepackage[left=35mm,right=15mm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm,bindingoffset=0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc} % указать кодировку русского текста
\usepackage[russian]{babel} % указать, что язык текста - русский

\usepackage{cmap}

\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\usepackage{indentfirst} 
\setlength{\parindent}{1.25cm}

\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{labelsep=endash}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
%    \keepXColumns
        \begin{longtabu} to \textwidth {| l | X |} 

        \caption{A long description of this awesomest table ever. No, seriously. Worth repeating: A long description of this awesomest table ever. No, seriously. }\\
        \hline 
        First & Second\\ \hline \hline
        \endfirsthead
        \captionsetup{singlelinecheck=off}
        \caption{A short one}\\
        \hline 
        First & Second\\ \hline
        \endhead
        Lols & \lipsum[150] \\ \hline
        Lols & \lipsum[150] \\ \hline
        Lols & \lipsum[150] \\ \hline
        Lols & \lipsum[150] \\ \hline
        Lols & \lipsum[150] \\ \hline
        Lols & \lipsum[150] \\ \hline
        Lols & \lipsum[150] \\ \hline
        Lols & \lipsum[150] \\ \hline
        Lols & \lipsum[150] \\ \hline
        Lols & \lipsum[150] \\ \hline
        Lols & \lipsum[150] \\ \hline
        \end{longtabu}
\end{document}
```